# GDAL conda install on Mac OS trouble

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install gdal on my new computer in the anaconda environment using conda but having issues. All I've done so far is install Anaconda for python 3.6 and [install gdal as described here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal) + a few other libraries using both conda and pip.

Trouble is when I try to run from "osgeo import gdal" the iPython console in spyder I get this error, which I'm not smart enough to interpret on my own:

> > > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >
> > > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > >            from osgeo import gdal
> > > >
> > > > File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/**init**.py", line 21, in 
> > > >            _gdal = swig_import_helper()
> > > >
> > > > File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/**init**.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
> > > >            _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
> > > >
> > > > File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
> > > >            return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
> > > >
> > > > File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
> > > >            return _load(spec)
> > > >
> > > > ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site->>>>packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: >>>>@rpath/libicui18n.58.dylib
> > > >          Referenced from: /anaconda/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
> > > >          Reason: image not found

Is there a problem with the conda install of gdal I'm using, or am I missing a piece?

Is there a different/easier way to start using gdal than this?

Comment: [Anaconda has gdal 2.10 included](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs). Is there a reason to install a version from the `conda-forge` channel?

Comment: Oh, if that's the case I've been mislead. I was under the impression Anaconda stopped including GDAL a long time ago and i'd need to install it on my own. Perhaps installing the conda-forge version broke things.

Comment: I re-installed macOS and anaconda on my MacBook and tried to install goal from the Anaconda channel but it wouldn't install. Instead I got this:

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - gdal -> numpy 1.8* -> python 2.6* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

Comment: I have to revise my comment. The link states GDAL is available for Linux/Mac with Python3.6 but not included in the installer. My bad.

Comment: The `gdal` package is available on `conda` but it basically never works on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the dependency versions are a bit messed up. GDAL is relying on there being older versions of certain libraries, but newer ones are installed by default. I've managed to get it working by forcing older versions of some of the dependencies. A minimal working `environment.yml` looks like this:

```
name: gis_project
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - gdal=2.3.1
  - ncurses=5.9=10
  - libspatialite=4.3.0a=19
```

In a new directory, run `conda env create`, activate the environment `conda activate gis_project` and check it works.